# Find IP's on network connected to 2nd ethernet port

Tags: networking, linux-networking

Noob question, do I need a router instead of a switch?

I connected 5 servers together.

1st server has 2 ethernet ports, 1st port to modem/internet, 2nd port to an unmanaged switch.

The switch has the other servers connected to it. I want to get the IP's of the other servers on the switch for the 1st server to use.

I can't find a way to list their IP's. And then it hit me, maybe they don't have IP's because there's no router assigning it to them? lol..

The image below illustrates the question. I want to know the IP's of "Other Servers".

[image: Router?]

Comment: The protocol that is allocating IPs on a network si called DHCP. You can install a DHCP server on Server1 (meaning that Server1 will act as a gateway for the 'other servers')

Comment: Ahh I see. I'm playing around with the idea of HA setups, if that's what I'm trying to achieve, I need to setup one or two of the "other servers" to be the DHCP servers? Looking for the answer on google right now. So humor me with the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure the "Other Servers" themselves would also like to know their IP addresses: you'll need to either tell them directly (i.e. assign them statically) or make sure something will tell them (i.e. make sure they can reach a DHCP server somehow).

The assignment of IP addresses must reflect the segment structure of the network, or else the IP protocol won't work as designed and you'd have to resort to ugly workarounds.

The answer depends on what Server 1 is doing to the network traffic.

If Server 1 is configured to only pass through IP traffic and not the raw Ethernet packets, then Server 1 is basically acting as a second **router**. You'd have two IP network segments: one between the router and Server 1's first network port, and another for Server 1's second network port and all the systems connected to the switch. In that case, the actual router will have no knowledge about IP addresses used in the network segment formed by the switch. If you don't want to assign static IP addresses to every device connected to the switch, it would be best to install a DHCP server to one of the systems connected to the switch.

A DHCP server does not *have* to be located within a router: any of the systems connected to the switch can be used for the DHCP server role, but since other systems in that network won't receive an IP address unless the DHCP server system is running, installing the DHCP server software to Server 1 might be a logical choice.

(With enterprise-grade systems, it would also be possible to use a simpler DHCP Relay software on Server 1 to pass any DHCP requests from the switch's network segment to the DHCP server within the router. But an average home/small-business router won't necessarily allow its DHCP server component to be configured for multiple network segments, or be capable of working with DHCP relays at all.)

---

If, on the other hand, Server 1 is configured to **bridge** traffic between its Ethernet ports, then it's basically acting as a two-port switch (or three-port, if you count Server 1's own network traffic as an extra port). It would effectively transparently pass through raw Ethernet packets from its port 1 to port 2 and vice versa whenever needed. In that case, the same IP address space segment would be used both between Server 1 and the router, and between all the systems connected to the switch, so the router's DHCP server can then serve all the systems.

Comment: Made perfect sense, thank you for going into detail.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the operating system of 1st Server, it might support DHCP Server (most Linux and Windows Servers support DHCP). If it does, just set it as a DHCP Server, and it will assign IP addresses to rest of the devices in your Network.

Now, if it does not support DHCP Server; then you will need to get a dedicated router. It does not need to replace the Switch, it can be plugged into the Switch, and will assign IP addresses to rest of the devices in your Network.

And finally, if there are only few servers, you can assign them Static IP addresses and that would also solve your problem.